# How to filter newest event using ethers

Tags: dapps, events, react, frontend

For context, I'm simply trying to display the balance of a USDC pool on my UI.

These are the relevant parts of my js:

```
const [usdcBalance, setusdcBalance]= useState(0);


const checkEvents = async() => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  let juniorPool = new ethers.Contract(juniorPoolAddress, JuniorPool.abi, provider)

  juniorPool.on("DepositMade", (capitalProvider, amount)=>{
    console.log(usdcBalance);
    console.log(parseInt(amount));
    setusdcBalance(parseInt(`${usdcBalance}`) + parseInt(amount));
  })
}
```

This is the output from my console, when I run the `deposit` function 3 times. The deposit function is the function that emits the `DepositMade` event. Each deposit I deposited 110 usdc:

[image]

The behavior I want is for setusdcBalance to take whatever the usdcBalance there is right now and add the amount added from a new deposit.

I realize that I could change the smart contract event to include blockNumber and use an if Statement on the event handler. But wouldn't that be really inefficient assuming that there might be thousands of past events? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use event filters:

`contract.filters.EVENT_NAME( ...args )` ⇒ `Filter`, which return a filter for EVENT_NAME, optionally filtering by additional constraints.

Only indexed event parameters may be filtered. If a parameter is null (or not provided) then any value in that field matches.

See: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--filters

Comment: Oh, it uses a Bloom filter, I see. Thank you very much for this. I'll try this approach.